# How do you call the people who love baseball?

Tags: american-english, nouns

How do you call the people who love baseball?
Do you usually use "baseball mania" or "baseball lover"?

Comment: Fanatic or Fan https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fanatic as in "a baseball fan" or "a fan of baseball". "Fan" is generally referring to someone who likes something. Everyone is a fan of something.  "Fanatic", however, can also mean more serious things like religious or political zealotry.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Frank Thomas has already answered in a comment but

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

**[fan](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fan)**

> someone who admires and supports a person, sport, sports team, etc
>   *He's an avid football fan.*

Just replace "football" by "baseball" in the example.

There is even a movie starring Robert DeNiro about a baseball lover titled **[The Fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fan_(1996_film))**.

[image: The Fan - Movie Poster]

Answer (score 0):

"Baseball fan" would be the obvious expression, but there is nothing wrong with "baseball lover".

The noun would be "baseball maniac". I wouldn't use that. It sounds like someone who is actually insane

Comment: Thanks! Because we usually use "mania" as not a serious meaning but a person who love something. Thanks!

Comment: @user96824 Mania in this sense would mean the craze or fashion for liking something (of itself or as a group), but a person experiencing it would be a maniac. This usage isn't really used any more though as mania is a serious psychological condition, and so shouldn't be used lightly.